# Elements in my web pages become distorted when i try to resize the browser window

Tags: css, html, resize, position, overlap

I am new to css, i created a webpage using css and it looks perfectly as expected when browser is maximized. But when i retrying the web page, the div elements i used in the page overlap each other making the perfect mess of things...!

I tried wrapping the div element.

```
#wrapper
{
min-width:500px;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

and also tried to set minimum-width attribute to parent div. Nothing worked out...

Please Help.

Comment: Do you have a link to your page or more code we can see?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is well below the minimum amount of information anyone can use to help you.

Comment: more code would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#wrapper
{
    min-width: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Actually you should thank @xpy - I only fixed the code layout.